# change UIColor from viewController to be use in UIView Class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to create a paint application and I'm seeting a variable with the color and pass it along to the UIView but I have abutton in the viewController to change the color but I can find a way to pass the change of the color to UIview:

ViewController (this work just fine):

```
paint *canvas=[[paint alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:canvas];
    canvas.colorSelected=colorSelected;
```

and I have a button to change the color selection:

- (IBAction)colorSelection:(id)sender

but because the instance of  canvas.colorSelected is release after canvas.colorSelected is set how can I change the color selection form the IBAction because if I create another instance it won't point to the same pointer of colorSelected. My question is how can change the colorSelected from the ibaction from viewController?

Answer (score 0):

it is really hard to understand what you are trying to do
if you want to set a background color just do:

`canvas.backgroundColor = colorSelected`

if you want to change a color by setting an `colorSelected` value 
you have to override a setter in your `paint` class
do something like this:

`in Paint.m`

```
- (void) setColorSelected:(UIColor*) color {
    _colorSelected = color;
    self.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

now when you do `canvas.colorSelected=[UIColor redColor];` your canvas will set `colorSelected` variable and change a background color as well

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an instance variable in your view controller to hold the reference to your **paint** object. Instead of using a local variable, like in your posted code, you assign the **paint** object to the instance variable. Then in your button handler, you can call the `colorSelected` property on the instance variable to update the color of the view.

Comment: An example of what? Adding an instance variable? If you don't know how to add an instance variable to your class then may I suggest you study up on the Objective-C programming language a bit more. Learning the basics of the language will really help in your coding efforts. The short answer is to add the instance variable to the @interface section in the .h file. Then the variable can be used in any method in the class.